# Subscribe to EC2 marketplace product via API

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-marketplace

Hi can I subscribe to an EC2 marketplace product via API ?

Can someone refer me to the documentation of it or (better) post an example of how to do it ?

I need to enable users from other accounts (not mine) to use their EC2 credentials (api and secret) and invoke an API call that subscribes them to an marketplace AMI of mine, so that they'll be able to use my marketplace AMI.
In general we know that we need to share it with them and we already know how to do it, but now we found that each user needs to subscribe to a marketplace product before launching an instance.